# Azure Functions - Always On and HTTP Triggers

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-functions-runtime

I am currently looking into occasional slow responses after periods of inactivity for an Azure Function application. The Azure Function runs on a dedicated plan, with host runtime version 1.x, and always on
enabled. The application uses queue messages to trigger the functions.

I noticed the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-scale#always-on) states *If you run on an App Service plan, you should enable the Always on setting so that your function app runs correctly. On an App Service plan, the functions runtime goes idle after a few minutes of inactivity, so only HTTP triggers will "wake up" your functions.*

I know that always on sends requests from the front-end load balancer to the application root url, however does that mean I have a http triggered function listening at the root url to ensure the function is always on. I tried this in my local development environment with a function which just returns an OK result and it seems to work. But is it necessary?

I would have thought not, as it was based on the web jobs host which just required the application pool to be not idle.

Any clarification would be extremely helpful.

Comment: Very interesting question! I've been looking info and I didn't find anything. Maybe can you turn the Always On and see if it stops being cold on without any http trigger function!!

Comment: This is mostly speculation on my behalf as I haven't really looked much into it. I would imagine that one of the host [admin endpoints](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/blob/dev/src/WebJobs.Script.WebHost/Controllers/HostController.cs) is called  to enable always on functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would appear that the always on functionality is implemented through the use of a rewrite in the [web.config](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/blob/a6d01a2ce62c1b2da517b98612e613eecc33c842/src/WebJobs.Script.WebHost/web.config#L24) of the function host.
A call to the application root url will be forwarded to `/admin/host/ping` which is part of the [host controller](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/blob/dev/src/WebJobs.Script.WebHost/Controllers/HostController.cs).

So in answer to your question

> ..does that mean I have a http triggered function listening at the root url to ensure the function is always on.

The answer is no.

Comment: I agree. I found that when I put a function at the root URI then it was never triggered with always on enabled. Then I saw in the host log that it was the ping endpoint was hit every five minutes rather than the root. 

I think this statement  _so only HTTP triggers will "wake up" your functions_ is incorrect. Do you agree?

Thanks for looking.